# Not receiving Push Notification in iOS after getting register the device in IBM MobileFirst Platform 8

Tags: ios, notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I am implementing Push Notification in a Cordova App. On Android, Push Notification working fine. But on iPhone, I am not receiving notifications.

I am able to register the iPhone device successfully for push notifications and I am also getting all tags that I created via the MFP server. While sending notification for iOS, I do get the delivery success message taht is 
"**the notification message was accepted for delivery.**"

But I do not get any notification on the iPhone.

I am using 
**IBM MobileFirst Foundation** 8.0.0-2016121916

**Developer Kit version**: 8.0.0.00-20161122-002317

Code :

```
function wlCommonInit(){

//initialize app for push notification
    MFPPush.initialize (
        function(successResponse) {
            alert("Push Notification Successfully intialized");
            MFPPush.registerNotificationsCallback(notificationReceived);
        },
        function(failureResponse) {
            alert("Failed to initialize");
        }
    );

    //Check device is Supported for push notification
    MFPPush.isPushSupported (
        function(successResponse) {
            alert("Device is Push Supported");
        },
        function(failureResponse) {
            alert("Failed to get push support status");
        }
    );

    //regiser app for push notification
    MFPPush.registerDevice( null,
        function(successResponse) {
                alert("Device Successfully registered");
        },
        function(failureResponse) {
            alert("Failed to register");
        }
    );

    var notificationReceived = function(message) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(message));
    };
}
```

Server log
[image]

```
2017-03-30 10:27:26.864028 MyProject[585:100605] [DEBUG] [OCLogger] Analytics data successfully sent to server.
2017-03-30 10:27:26.874357 MyProject[585:100605] Response Content : {"createdTime":"2017-03-29T14:27:31Z","lastUpdatedTime":"2017-03-30T04:54:33Z","createdMode":"API","deviceId":"20D322D5-781B-4C2C-82CE-673648AAB6FD","userId":"anonymous","token":"8c6c071ee6095e0ef5888abf8b885984fc02860c8a837f58be8118df8c353227","platform":"A","href":"http://192.168.10.126:9080/imfpush/v1/apps/com.MyProject.mobile/devices/20D322D5-781B-4C2C-82CE-673648AAB6FD"}
2017-03-30 10:27:48.280985 MyProject[585:100651] [] nw_coretls_read_one_record tls_handshake_process: [-9802]
2017-03-30 10:27:49.021119 MyProject[585:100651] [] nw_coretls_read_one_record tls_handshake_process: [-9802]
2017-03-30 10:27:49.026982 MyProject[585:100657] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
2017-03-30 10:28:21.129769 MyProject[585:100682] void SendDelegateMessage(NSInvocation *): delegate (webView:runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:initiatedByFrame:) failed to return after waiting 10 seconds. main run loop mode: kCFRunLoopDefaultMode
2017-03-30 10:28:21.212950 MyProject[585:100605] Finished load of: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/03675139-9EBE-4F42-B07D-45C98D40A440/MyProject.app/www/index.html#/appTour
2017-03-30 10:28:32.822257 MyProject[585:100832] Inside sendRequest : WLRequestBuilder
2017-03-30 10:28:33.171541 MyProject[585:100605] Response Content : {"subscribed":[{"tagName":"promotional","userId":"anonymous","subscriptionId":"528","deviceId":"20D322D5-781B-4C2C-82CE-673648AAB6FD","href":"http://192.168.10.126:9080/imfpush/v1/apps/com.MyProject.mobile/subscriptions"},{"tagName":"transectional","userId":"anonymous","subscriptionId":"529","deviceId":"20D322D5-781B-4C2C-82CE-673648AAB6FD","href":"http://192.168.10.126:9080/imfpush/v1/apps/com.MyProject.mobile/subscriptions"},{"tagName":"yy","userId":"anonymous","subscriptionId":"530","deviceId":"20D322D5-781B-4C2C-82CE-673648AAB6FD","href":"http://192.168.10.126:9080/imfpush/v1/apps/com.MyProject.mobile/subscriptions"}],"subscriptionExists":[],"tagsNotFound":{"code":"FPWSE0001E","message":"Not Found - The target resource 'tagNames' does not exist. Check the 'tags' parameter.","tags":[]}}
2017-03-30 10:28:33.176354 MyProject[585:100605] [DEBUG] [OCLogger] The log file is empty. There are no persisted logs to send.
2017-03-30 10:28:33.183157 MyProject[585:100605] Inside sendRequest : WLRequestBuilder
2017-03-30 10:28:33.298817 MyProject[585:100605] Response Content :
2017-03-30 10:28:33.300344 MyProject[585:100605] [DEBUG] [OCLogger] Analytics data successfully sent to server.
2017-03-30 10:28:37.770125 MyProject[585:100605] WL.JSONStore success
```

Comment: Can we see the server log?

Comment: @TyLy see updated server log.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs, it is evident that your MFP server cannot communicate to APNS. Connection from MFP server to APNS is timing out.

Verify that your network rules or firewall is configured to allow outbound access from MFP server to APNS. Ensure all the required ports are open and allow inbound and outbound communication. While at it, make sure you allow access for APNS hostnames and not specifically whitelist IP's.

For more details on the ports and domains refer to this [link](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/notifications/sending-notifications/#apple-push-notifications-service).